# Create a flexible grid in CSS that also has operations performed on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've forgotten a lot about CSS/HTML and how one might control it from JavaScript code. So I'm creating a grid with 1 row and 4 columns, with the width of each column being 25% of the window size (maintained even if page is resized). Each cell in the grid can also contain another 1x4 flexible grid, and the border of the grid is 1px black.

Based on the value of the window size, if < 720px, then 1x4 grid becomes a 2x2 grid (3rd and 4th columns slide into the 2nd row), if window size < 360px, 1x4 grid becomes a 4x1 grid (each column slides under the one before it, so the 2nd column slides under the 1st, 3rd slides under the 2nd, etc.).

This is about as far as I remember how to do; if anyone can jog my memory on how to complete this fully, that'd be of great help.

```css
.w3-row {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col m4 l3">
    <p>12 columns on a small screen, 4 on a medium screen, and 3 on a large screen.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col m8 l9">
    <p>12 columns on a small screen, 8 on a medium screen, and 9 on a large screen.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be more easy with bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah that's why I forgot how to do this; but I'm asked to do it using just vanilla JS + HTML and CSS

Comment: you can use @media (max-width: 1200px) { some style }. You need to change max-media based on media size.

Comment: Changing CSS based on window width is done via [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Depending on how long ago was the last time you did CSS, you might have done [grids using floats](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/) like boostrap/foundation did, but now browsers support [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) layouts.